# Merge is Missing Some Values in R

Tags: r, merge, vlookup

I have 2 dataframes: one has my `data` and another is like a vlookup table (called `PlanMap`), where I look up the `LeavePlanCode` in the `PlanMap` to get the `Plan.Type`.

To perform the vlookup, I have done the following code: 
`data <- merge(data, PlanMap[,c(1:2)], by.x = "LeavePlanCode", by.y = "From.Raw.Data", all.x = TRUE)` 
where `From.Raw.Data` is the same thing as the `LeavePlanCode`, just in the main dataset.

The merge works correctly for 415,000 of my rows, however 4,000 of them are showing up as NA. These NAs narrow down to 3 (of 150) `LeavePlanCode` which **are also** in my `PlanMap`, so they should be pulled in, just like the rest of the 150 plan codes are.

Can anyone explain why the vlookup on these 3 isn't working??

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: They probably aren't exact matches. Maybe in one data frame there is extra white space? `"Not match"` vs `"Not  match"` (two spaces in the middle) or `"Not match "` (trailing space), or maybe there are capitalization differences, or something else. Inspect them carefully and there will be a difference.

Comment: Have you checked, whether these 3 are actually existent in the `From.Raw.Data`. My first guess would be that they are not.

Comment: Maybe this helps as well: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html - it explains joins for relational data. You're doing an outer join (section 13.4.3.)

Comment: Thanks. @Gregor--reinstateMonica--I have checked for any extra spaces and capitalized letters and they are matching. So strange that it's just these 3 LeavePlanCodes that aren't working in the Vlookup...

Comment: @Georgery: Yes, I have checked that. Thx

Comment: @Cath: I cannot provide my dataset for confidentiality reasons...

Comment: The idea is to have data like your data, you don't have to put the actual data, just some that can reproduce the problem

Comment: @Gregor: figured out that the issue was there was some white space at the end of the columns for only that ```LeavePlanCode```. I fixed this by using the strip.white = TRUE when I read in the csv file. Thanks for your help!